# AngularJS - restore the original rows order with ng-table

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I've enabled sorting in ng-table with $scope.tableParams.sorting() method. Mouse clicks on the column headers will switch between ascending and descending order, but I would like to switch it between ascending, descending and the original (unsorted) row order. Any hints how to achieve this?

I tried something like that:

```
if ($scope.tableParams.isSortBy(colName, 'asc')) {
       $scope.tableParams.sorting({colName: 'desc'});
 }
else if($scope.tableParams.isSortBy(colName, 'desc')) {
      $scope.tableParams.sorting({colName: ''});
 }
else{
      $scope.tableParams.sorting({colName: 'asc'});
 }
```

tnx.

Comment: Can You make plunker and write template code?

Comment: if you 'console.log($scope.tableParams.isSortBy(colName, 'desc'));'  is it ever true? I tried to find a solution, but I can't get that value to become true

Comment: if ($scope.tableParams.isSortBy('company', 'asc')) is true after sorting this column ascending. make sure you have this col name on your table object.

Comment: Yeah, I have the same column on my table, but it still wont be true. But if you get it to be true, then your own test should work, no?

Comment: No, sorting({colName: ''}) does not make any change.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reset the sorting with the help of a button:

```
<button id="resetSorting" type="button" ng-click="resetSort()"> Reset </button>
```

and a function:

```
$scope.resetSort = function(){
    $scope.tableParams.sorting({colName: ''});
};
```

Edit: I guess your code looks something like this:

```
            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 10,
                sorting: {
                    colName: 'desc'
                }
            }, {
                total: $scope.data.length, // length of data
                getData: function($defer, params) {
                    // use build-in angular filter
                    var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                        $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, params.orderBy()) :
                        $scope.data;
                    orderedData = params.filter() ?
                        $filter('filter')(orderedData, params.filter()) :
                        orderedData;

                    params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
                    $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));

                // check if value is true
                 console.log($scope.tableParams.isSortBy(colName, 'asc'));

                if ($scope.tableParams.isSortBy(colName, 'asc')) {
                   $scope.tableParams.sorting({colName: ''});
                    }
                }
            });
```

If you look at my code now, when I try and sort my table so that 'colName' is ascending, I still get the value 'false' in console. This means that this:

```
if ($scope.tableParams.isSortBy(colName, 'asc')) {
    $scope.tableParams.sorting({colName: ''});
}
```

Will never trigger, and the table won't be unsorted.

I think you have the same problem, your if's and else sentences don't trigger, or do they?

Comment: It does not make any changes to the sorting. if it was asc sort it stay that way.